# in C++ , what's so special about "_MOVE_H"?

Tags: c++, include-guards

I have a C++ file like this

```
#ifndef _MOVE_H
#define _MOVE_H

class Move {
    int x, y;
public:
    Move(int initX = 0, int initY = 0) : x(initX), y(initY) {}
    int getX() { return x; }
    void setX(int newX) { x = newX; }
    int getY() { return y; }
    void setY(int newY) { y = newY; }
};

#endif
```

And to my amazement, all the code between `#ifndef` and `#endif` is simply ignored by the compiler (I swear that I am not defining `_MOVE_H` anywhere else), and I have all kinds of errors about missing definitions. I was thinking that I did something wrong, but when I try to use another key (like `_MOVE_Ha`, everything is back to normal. Does `_MOVE_H` mean something special in C++ ?

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04, GCC 4.4.3, if that matters.

Thanks,

Comment: may be the one of the library files you are including using that for its inclusion guard? did you check that? btw, I normally prefix it with the project name so as to avoid exactly this type of issue.

Comment: Another reason to use `#pragma once` instead of `#define` include guards...

Comment: @Inverse, `#pragma once` is a compiler extension and not supported by all compilers. Include guards are the only safe compiler independent means of preventing multiple inclusion.

Comment: @Nathan Ernst: I know, but if you're using any of the 3 major compilers, `#pragma once` saves the compiler from having to open and process the same guarded header over and over every compile.

Comment: There's no need for a compiler to open and process a normal header either. The idea of recognizing include guards was invented and implemented over a decade ago, IIRC.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

just run grep _MOVE_H in /usr/include/c++ on your machine

for me :

```
c++/4.5.0/bits/move.h:#ifndef _MOVE_H
```

As a rule of thumb, don't use *things* (really anything) prefixed by `_` or `__`. It's reserved for internal usage.
Use `SOMETHING_MOVE_H` (usually name of the company, ...).

I guess it's a new header used to add the move semantic to c++0x.

Comment: To clarify the underscore rule, the following things are reserved: any *global* name prefixed by `_`, any name of any sort prefixed by `__`, and any name of any sort prefixed by `_` and beginning with a capital letter. The OP runs afoul of the first and third rules.

Comment: Any name containing a `__` at all is reserved.  It need not be prefixed.

Answer (score 6):

Anything beginning with an underscore then capital letter is reserved to the implementation. (i.e. `_M`).  I think in general you want to stay away from leading underscores.

Answer (score 4):

I believe gcc has an include file called move.h that includes the sentinel _MOVE_H. Presumably you have collided with this. Use a different identifier, preferably one that doesn't start with an underscore. I put a GUID in mine, but then I'm **really** obsessive :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's a trick to prevent the same header file being included more than once. The actual value you #define doesn't matter - so long as it's only defined in that header file, the convention is NAME_HEADER_FILE_H in capitals

See also this discussion on [#pragma once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787533/is-pragma-once-a-safe-include-guard)

Comment: sorry, that's not really the problem. the problem is, my file isn't being included at all.