# Problem with cross #include across header files with classes

Tags: c++

Working on a simple game in c++ but I keep stumbling on a cross #include problem. Essentially the problem is like this:

I have a `Chunk` class that depends on `Tile` and `Entity` but `Entity` **also** depends on `Chunk`.

**Entity.hpp**

```
#include "Chunk.hpp"

class Entity {
    public:
        Chunk in_chunk;
};
```

**Chunk.hpp**

```
#include "Entity.hpp" // <-- not possible

class Chunk {
    public:
        std::vector<std::vector<Tile>> tiles;
        std::vector<Entity> needs_update;
};
```

Now I know [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24625401/c-header-file-cross-include) has been asked before and that this can be solved by using forward declarations and pointing to the class, but, as far as I am aware, this will also mean that everytime I need to access this vector filled with `Tile`s and its `needs_update` member I will need to do so by using pointers.
This seems like a very bad solution and I feel like there must be a better way.

So, is the only solution by pointing to the class or is there another way to get around this?

<sup>Mind you, I am quite new to c++ and just starting to grasp the concepts of pointers and references, if I am missing something trivial here please point me in the right direction and perhaps I can fix this myself.</sup>

Comment: Is it intended that a `Entity` _owns_ a `Chunk`? Right now, each instance of `Entity` will contain an instance of `Chunk` with all the tiles and entities it contains. I strongly doubt this is what you want. Shouldn't all the chunks be stored in some other datastructure and each `Entity` should then _refer_ to the `Chunk` it's currently located in?

Comment: There's nothing about forward references that automatically requires pointers to be used. You must've misunderstood something.

Comment: *"I will need to do so by using pointers"* - that's not necessarily true. The *implementation* of `Chunk` needs to see `Entity` as a formal type, but the declaration does not. I.e. So long as `Chunk.cpp` (assuming there is one by the looks of this) sees Entity.hpp prior to pumping entities into `needs_update` with actual code, this can work with forward decls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, is the only solution by pointing to the class or is there another way to get around this?

Forward declarations do not require usage of pointers. See [fixed example on wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hXXHY7ug12p0EzIh).

(Since C++17 std::vector actually can hold incomplete (forward declared) types).

Never the less, your example is "strange". Entity is an owner of Chunk, but Chunk contains Entities by value? It seems that either Entity should refer to a chunk (by reference/pointer or some other mechanism like id) or Chunk should refer to Entities that needs to be updated.

Right now it is something like this:

Every entity contains (distinct) Chunk.
Every Chunk contains two-dimensional vector of (distinct) tiles and vector of (distinct) Entities.
Every Entity from that vector contains (distinct) Chunk and so on.

If two entities should be able to "refer" to one chunk then that chunk should be outside of an entities. If two Chunks should be able to "refer" to same entities then that Entities should be stored outside Chunks and Chunk refer to them by pointer, reference, smart-pointer or an id.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understands the problem with my code now. Right now I don't know whether I should use smart-pointers or normal pointers. In the context of my program, which would you say?

Comment: @Duco Standard smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`, `std::weak_ptr`) are not only about pointing to objects but also about ownership and lifetime of controlled objects. You should use normal pointers / references to refer to objects which lifetime is guarantied to be long enough.

Comment: You should use std::unique_ptr instead of naked pointers when allocating memory (and std::make_unique instead of `new`) that should be destroyed when a handle's (owning pointer's) lifetime ends. If possible prefer creating objects by on the stack - no need to use unique_ptr/`new` if object always is destroyed in the same scope that it was created. `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr` should be used (mostly) only if there is a shared ownership of an object - object lifetime ends when all handles to it go out of scope (it is pretty rare requirement, so `std::shared_ptr` should not be a default)

Comment: In your case you should probably use naked pointers to refer to already created object. Be aware that pointers to objects that are stored inside std::vector become invalid after insert/erase on that vector (see pointers and iterators invalidation).

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is a circular dependency, which means that each file includes itself. The most common way to resolve this is by using forward declarations.

> as far as I am aware, this will also mean that everytime I need to access this vector filled with Tiles and its needs_update member I will need to do so by using pointers

Nope, not at all. What your doing by a forward declaration is that you tell the compiler "Hey dude, there's a class/ struct named 'something' somewhere. Just leave it to the linker to figure it out". Then the compiler compiles it fine and its the duty of the linker to link them to the class definition (the linker will throw an error if it cant find the definition). 
The only down side is that you need to include the class header if your planning on accessing the members of that forward declared class/ struct.

> So, is the only solution by pointing to the class or is there another way to get around this?

My approach would be something like this, 
Lets say that `Chunk.hpp` has the forward declaration of `Entity`. Then when accessing the members of `Entity` using a function, move the function definition to a source file (as you would normally do except for templated classes) and include the `Entity.hpp` file there so that it can access the member functions of `Entity`.