# Making a methods friend in nested namespaces

Tags: c++, namespaces, nested

Following problem: I am currently adding namespaces into my project and there's one thing that i can't seem to get around, friending methods in nested namespaces. If class x is in the namespace a and namespace b but class y that wants to friend the method in class x is in namespace a and namespace b it can't work since class y doesn't have a clue about namespace b, but you can't include the header of class x because class x already includes class y. Is there a way to fix this ?

Errors i get:

> 'Kinnon::Time::Time::m_DeltaTime': cannot access private member declared in class 'Kinnon::Time::Time'
>   'Main': is not a class or namespace name
>   'Main': is not a class or namespace name

Time.h

```
#pragma once
namespace Kinnon { namespace Time {

class Time
{
    friend void Main::MainComponent::run();
public:
static const float &getDeltaTime();
private:
    Time();
    static float m_DeltaTime;
};
} }
```

MainComponent.h

```
#pragma once
#include <chrono>
#include "..\graphics\Window.h"
#include "..\input\Input.h"
#include "..\time\Time.h"

namespace Kinnon { namespace Main { 

typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Clock;
typedef std::chrono::duration<float> fsec;

class MainComponent
{
public:
    MainComponent(const char *title, unsigned int width, unsigned int height);
    ~MainComponent();
    void run();
    void tick();
    void render();
private :
    Graphics::Window m_Window;

};
} }
```

MainComponent.run() method:

```
namespace Kinnon { namespace Main {
void MainComponent::run()
    {
        auto lastTime = Clock::now();
        auto currentTime = Clock::now();
        while(!m_Window.shouldClose())
        {
            lastTime = Clock::now();
            tick();
            render();
            currentTime = Clock::now();
            fsec passedTime = currentTime - lastTime;
            Time::Time::m_DeltaTime = passedTime.count();
        }
    }
    }}
```

Comment: `MainComponent.h` doesn't appear to have a need to include `Time.h`. If you take that out, then `Time.h` could include `MainComponent.h`

Comment: @igor now that you say it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik If that is the answer, please make it an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as follows:

1. Use Include guards within `MainComponent.h`, and take out the `#include "Time.h"` from it.
2. Put your `MainComponent.run()` function in a `.cpp` file, and include both `Time.h` and `MainComponent.h` in it.
3. include `MainComponent.h` in `Time.h`.

So you'll end up with something like this:
in `MainComponent.h`:

```
#ifndef __MAIN_COMPONENT_H__
#define __MAIN_COMPONENT_H__
#pragma once
#include <chrono>
#include "..\graphics\Window.h"
#include "..\input\Input.h"

namespace Kinnon { namespace Main { 

typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Clock;
typedef std::chrono::duration<float> fsec;

class MainComponent
{
public:
    MainComponent(const char *title, unsigned int width, unsigned int height);
    ~MainComponent();
    void run();
    void tick();
    void render();
private :
    Graphics::Window m_Window;

};
} }
#endif
```

in `Time.h`:

```
#include "MainComponent.h"
#pragma once
namespace Kinnon { namespace Time {

class Time
{
    friend void Main::MainComponent::run();
public:
static const float &getDeltaTime();
private:
    Time();
    static float m_DeltaTime;
};
} }
```

and in `MainComponent.cpp`:

```
#include "MainComponent.h"
#include "Time.h"
namespace Kinnon { namespace Main {
void MainComponent::run()
    {
        auto lastTime = Clock::now();
        auto currentTime = Clock::now();
        while(!m_Window.shouldClose())
        {
            lastTime = Clock::now();
            tick();
            render();
            currentTime = Clock::now();
            fsec passedTime = currentTime - lastTime;
            Time::Time::m_DeltaTime = passedTime.count();
        }
    }
    }}
```

If you'd like another solution, you can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8526965/3002584) (using forward declaration, with each class keeping a pointer to an instance of the other class).

Comment: this fixed it. some how i was thinking too far.