# How to resolve ssertion fail when allocating array of objects of class from mutually included file?

Tags: c++, assertion

I have two classes `Mat3` and `Vec3`, placed in separate files. `Mat3` is composed of array of `Vec3`, and `Vec3` uses `Mat3` in some of calculations, so those files include each other. I have placed prototypes of them in headers, but in `Mat3` it's problematic. Array of `Vec3` does not compile due to incomplete type, so I changed it to `Vec3*` and planned to allocate memory in constructor, but there is assertion fail when using `new` or `malloc` (I know, that `new` uses `malloc`, just pointing out combinations I used) that goes:

> Mapper: malloc.c:2379: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.

So now I have no idea how to manage all of these. Can you help?

I'm placing simplified classes below, for better understanding:

```
---------Vec3.h-----------
#ifndef VEC3_H
#define VEC3_H
#include <cmath>
#include <assert.h>
#include "Vec2.h"
#include "Mat3.h"
namespace API
{
    namespace Data
    {
        struct Mat3;
        struct Vec3
        {
            float X = 0.0f;
            float Y = 0.0f;
            float Z = 0.0f;
            Vec3();
            Vec3(float, float, float);
            Vec3(Vec3*);
            void Rotate(const Vec3);
        };
    }
}
#endif
```

```
---------Vec3.cpp-----------
#include "Vec3.h"

API::Data::Vec3::Vec3()
{
}

API::Data::Vec3::Vec3(float x, float y, float z)
{
    X = x;
    Y = y;
    Z = z;
}

API::Data::Vec3::Vec3(Vec3* original) : API::Data::Vec3::Vec3(original->X, original->Y, original->Z)
{
}

void API::Data::Vec3::Rotate(const API::Data::Vec3 angles)
{
    Mat3 rotationMatrix = Mat3(0.0f);
    Mat3 xRotation = Mat3(0.0f);
    Mat3 yRotation = Mat3(0.0f);
    Mat3 zRotation = Mat3(0.0f);
    xRotation.XRotation(angles.X);
    ///
    yRotation.YRotation(angles.Y);
    ///
    zRotation.ZRotation(angles.Z);

    rotationMatrix = xRotation * yRotation * zRotation;
    Vec3 effect = rotationMatrix * (*this);
    X = effect.X;
    Y = effect.Y;
    Z = effect.Z;
}
```

```
-------Mat3.h------------
#ifndef MAT3_H
#define MAT3_H
#include <vector>
#include <assert.h>
#include "Vec3.h"
namespace API
{
    namespace Data
    {
        struct Vec3;
        struct Mat3
        {
        private:
            Vec3* _columns = nullptr;
        public:
            Mat3();
            Mat3(const Mat3&);
            Mat3(float);
        };
    }
}
#endif // !MAT3_H
```

```
-------Mat3.cpp-------
API::Data::Mat3::Mat3(float value)
{
    _columns = new API::Data::Vec3[3]; // Assertion fail fires here
    //OR
    // _columns = (API::Data::Vec3*)malloc(3 * sizeof(API::Data::Vec3));
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        _columns[i] = API::Data::Vec3();
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            _columns[i][j] = value;
        }
    }
}

API::Data::Mat3::Mat3() : API::Data::Mat3(0.0f)
{
}

API::Data::Mat3::Mat3(const API::Data::Mat3& original) : API::Data::Mat3(0.0f)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            _columns[i][j]= original[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Code has been updated to minimal compilable version.

Comment: Having classes include each other is a bad idea, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526819/c-header-files-including-each-other-mutually/8526965

Comment: Please post a minmal compiling example.

Comment: @Superlokkus done.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me :

**Vec3.h**

```
#ifndef VEC3_H
#define VEC3_H
#include <cmath>
#include <assert.h>
namespace API
{
    namespace Data
    {
        struct Mat3;//forward declaration
        struct Vec3
        {
            float X = 0.0f;
            float Y = 0.0f;
            float Z = 0.0f;
            Vec3();
            Vec3(float, float, float);
            Vec3(Vec3*);
            void Rotate(const Vec3);
        };
    }
}
#endif
```

**Vec3.cpp**

```
#include "Vec3.h"
#include "Mat3.h"

API::Data::Vec3::Vec3()
{
}

API::Data::Vec3::Vec3(float x, float y, float z)
{
    X = x;
    Y = y;
    Z = z;
}

API::Data::Vec3::Vec3(Vec3* original) : API::Data::Vec3::Vec3(original->X, original->Y, original->Z)
{
}

void API::Data::Vec3::Rotate(const API::Data::Vec3 angles)
{
    Mat3 rotationMatrix = Mat3(0.0f);
    Mat3 xRotation = Mat3(0.0f);
    Mat3 yRotation = Mat3(0.0f);
    Mat3 zRotation = Mat3(0.0f);
    //Comments because you have not implemented rotations for instance
    /*xRotation.XRotation(angles.X);
    ///
    yRotation.YRotation(angles.Y);
    ///
    zRotation.ZRotation(angles.Z);

    rotationMatrix = xRotation * yRotation * zRotation;
    Vec3 effect = rotationMatrix * (*this);
    X = effect.X;
    Y = effect.Y;
    Z = effect.Z;*/
}
```

**Mat3.h**

```
#ifndef MAT3_H
#define MAT3_H
#include <assert.h>
namespace API
{
    namespace Data
    {
        struct Vec3;//forward declaration
        struct Mat3
        {
        private:
            Vec3* _columns = nullptr;
        public:
            Mat3();
            Mat3(const Mat3&);
            Mat3(float);
            ~Mat3();
        };
    }
}
#endif // !MAT3_H
```

**Mat3.cpp**

```
#include "Mat3.h"
#include "Vec3.h"


API::Data::Mat3::Mat3(float value)
{
    _columns = new API::Data::Vec3[3];
    assert(_columns != 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        _columns[i] = API::Data::Vec3();
        _columns[i].X = value;
        _columns[i].Y = value;
        _columns[i].Z = value;
    }
}

API::Data::Mat3::Mat3() : API::Data::Mat3(0.0f)
{
}

API::Data::Mat3::Mat3(const API::Data::Mat3& original) : API::Data::Mat3(0.0f)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {

        _columns[i].X = original._columns[i].X;
        _columns[i].Y = original._columns[i].Y;
        _columns[i].Z = original._columns[i].Z;
    }
}


API::Data::Mat3::~Mat3() {
    delete[] _columns;
}
```

In C/C++, when you play with the "cross reference" system, you always put a forward declaration of your class in headers and it's useless to include headers of this class.
[circular dependency-wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency). So, in ".cpp" files, you should include your headers to have the **definitions** of your class (and not only the **declaration**).

One other thing : if you allocate data on the heap (with `new[]`) in the constructor, you should remove this in the destructor (with `delete[]`).