# extern keyword "missing type specifier"

Tags: c++, c, extern

I'm creating a DLL using Visual C++ Express, and when declaring
`extern ValveInterfaces* VIFace` inside `Required.h`, the compiler is telling me that `ValveInterfaces` isn't defined. (I want to expose `VIFace` to any file including `Required.h`)

Here is the structure of my files:

**DLLMain.cpp**

```
#include "Required.h" //required header files, such as Windows.h and the SDK  

ValveInterfaces* VIFace;  

//the rest of the file
```

---

**Required.h**

```
#pragma once
//include Windows.h, and the SDK
#include "ValveInterfaces.h"

extern ValveInterfaces* VIFace; //this line errors
```

---

**ValveInterfaces.h**

```
#pragma once
#ifndef _VALVEINTERFACES_H_
#define _VALVEINTERFACES_H_
#include "Required.h"

class ValveInterfaces
{
public:
    ValveInterfaces(void);
    ~ValveInterfaces(void);
    static CreateInterfaceFn CaptureFactory(char *pszFactoryModule);
    static void* CaptureInterface(CreateInterfaceFn fn, char * pszInterfaceName);
    //globals
    IBaseClientDLL* gClient;
    IVEngineClient* gEngine;
};
#endif
```

Screenshot of errors:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZUph.png

Comment: You shouldn't use reserved names for include guards. Although it's not the cause of your particular problem (that's due to the circular inclusion of `ValveInterfaces.h` and `Required.h`), it can cause [similar problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345159/in-c-whats-so-special-about-move-h).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That first error:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
```

is a dead giveaway that the `ValveInterfaces` type has *not* been defined at the point where you first try to use it.

This almost invariably occurs because the type of `ValveInterfaces` is unknown. It's a little hard to tell since you've cut out huge swathes of `ValveInterfaces.h` but, even if it's defined there, it could be a weird combination of `#pragma once` and the apparent misplacement of the `_REQUIRED_H` include guards (they would normally be in `required.h`) which is causing you grief.

Comment: Huh, that's what I thought, but why isn't it? I included the header file before I declare it as an extern.

Comment: I've pasted the entire ValveInterfaces.h inside. I think my problem is that ValveInterfaces.h is including Required.h, which is also including ValveInterfaces.h.

Comment: You may be right. I would drop the `pragma once` altogether and use the more portable include guards. And get rid of circular references as well.

Answer (score 3):

Note that circular inclusion, like how you have `Required.h` and `ValveInterfaces.h`, is usually a code smell. If you break up the circular reference, problems like these are less likely to come up.

What you can try and do is forward declare as much as you can in `ValveInterfaces.h` and keep it self-contained. It doesn't look like ValveInterfaces needs everything from Requires.h so don't include it.

```
#ifndef VALVEINTERFACES_H
#define VALVEINTERFACES_H
// CreateInterfaceFn probably need to be fully defined
// so just pull whatever header has that. Don't include 
// Required.h here, there's no need for it.

class IBaseClientDLL;
class IVEngineClient;
class ValveInterfaces
{
public:
    ValveInterfaces();
    ~ValveInterfaces();
    static CreateInterfaceFn CaptureFactory(char *pszFactoryModule);
    static void* CaptureInterface(CreateInterfaceFn fn, char * pszInterfaceName);
    //globals
    IBaseClientDLL* gClient;
    IVEngineClient* gEngine;
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `ValveInterface` (singular) but declaring `ValveInterfaces` (plural).

Comment: Sorry, typed it in wrong... Should be ValveInterfaces, edited it. Intellisense doesn't detect the error (?)