# How can I define the class fields/methods in less space in C++

Tags: c++, header-files

That's my header:

```
#ifndef MYCLASSES_H_
#define MYCLASSES_H_

#define ARRAY_SIZE(x) (sizeof((x)) / sizeof((x)[0]))

namespace mynamespace {

class A
{
    class B
    {
        class C
        {
            void doStuff(B *pB);
        }

        static const C SOME_ARRAY[];
        static const int SOME_ARRAY_COUNT;
    }
}

} //namespace mynamespace
#endif /* MYCLASSES_H_ */
```

And that's the CPP:

```
#include "myclasses.h"

namespace mynamespace {

void A::B::C::doStuff(A::B *pB)
{
    /* ... */
}

const A::B::C A::B::SOME_ARRAY[] = {
    /*...*/
};

const A::B::SOME_ARRAY_COUNT = ARRAY_SIZE(

} //namespace mynamespace
```

What shall I do to make the definitions in the .CPP file have shorter names? It's incredibly cumbersome.

Comment: Do you really need 3 inner classes? It is not better just to use inheritance?

Comment: Man walks into a doctor. He says "Doctor, my head hurts when I bang it against the wall". Doctor says: "Don't bang your head on the wall and your head will stop hurting". Since B and C are in a private section of class A the world can not see them. So no need to nest them inside A just make them non visable to the outside world. The easy way to do this is to put them in an anonymous namespace inside the source file.

Comment: @LokiAstari I was about to write that. btw where is the "convert a comment to an answer" button? ;)

Comment: You should not really use that array size macro, it will fail when x is a pointer (or will suddently decay into one). Use a ` template <typename T, size_t N> size_t array_size(T(&) [N] ) { return N; }` which will error out when not passed an actual array.

Comment: You shouldn't use reserved names for include guards, or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345159/) might happen.

Comment: @MikeSeymour My mistake, sry.

Comment: @PlasmaHH, Thanks, I'll remember that. I'm generally cautious not to use it on decayed arrays, but didn't know about your solution. :-)

Comment: @LokiAstari, would you elaborate on your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore: Unless it uses # or ## there are seldom cases where a value producing function style macro can not be replaced by a template, and it is often worth searching for a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Man walks into a doctor. He says "Doctor, my head hurts when I bang it against the wall". Doctor says: "Don't bang your head on the wall and your head will stop hurting".

Since B and C are in a private section of class A the world can not see them.

So there is no need to nest them inside A just make them non visible to the outside world.
The easy way to do this is to put them in an anonymous namespace inside the source file.

```
#ifndef MYCLASSES_H_
#define MYCLASSES_H_

#define ARRAY_SIZE(x) (sizeof((x)) / sizeof((x)[0]))

namespace mynamespace {

class A
{
}

} //namespace mynamespace
#endif /* MYCLASSES_H_ */
```

And that's the CPP:

```
#include "myclasses.h"


namespace
{
    // This is an anonymouse namespace
    // It does not export it symbols outside the compilation unit.
    // So only A should be able to see them
    class B
    {
            static const C SOME_ARRAY[];
            static const int SOME_ARRAY_COUNT;
    };
    class C
    {
            void doStuff(B *pB);
    };
}
void C::doStuff(B *pB)
{
    /* ... */
}

const C B::SOME_ARRAY[] = {
    /*...*/
};

const B::SOME_ARRAY_COUNT = ARRAY_SIZE(
```

Comment: Thanks. Highly appreciate your efforts :-)

Answer (score 2):

May be try to use a using declaration:

```
using A::B;
```

Comment: That only works for names in a namespace scope; these are in a class scope.

Answer (score 2):

typedefs let you shorten naming:

```
#include "MYCLASSES.h"

namespace mynamespace {

typedef A::B b;
typedef b::C c;

void c::doStuff(b *pB)
{
    /* ... */
}

const c b::SOME_ARRAY[100] = {
    /*...*/
};

const int b::SOME_ARRAY_COUNT = ARRAY_SIZE(SOME_ARRAY);

} //namespace mynamespace
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot. This is just a syntactic property of C++.

As a consequence, you should prefer flat nesting hierarchies in C++: don’t nest classes endlessly, put them into the same upper-level namespace. In other languages that’s a big no-no since it leaks implementation details to the public interface.<sup>1</sup>

Not so in C++, since here you have distinct compilation units to enforce encapsulation and information hiding. So flat hierarchies are actually fine for the most part.

---

<sup>1</sup> But even in other languages three nested classes is pushing the envelope.

Answer (score 0):

There's no **clean way** to do it. If it were nested namespaces, you could use `using` or `namespace aliasing`.

Since it's classes, the best I can think of is:

```
#define B A::B
#define C B::C
```

but it's definetely not clean. I wouldn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real way of doing this other than something like:

```
    #define AB mynamespace::A::B;
```

To allow this:

```
    mynamespace::A::B::C myobj;
```

Note that many programmers (myself included) think that this is bad practice because it is not obvious what AB is.

To become:

```
    AB::C myobj;
```

You cannot use 'using' for classes, only namespaces. So in a cpp file you can do:

```
    using mynamespace;
    A::B::C myobj;
```

But not:

```
    using mynamespace::A::B;
    C myobj;
```

Generally though, many people agree that best practice is to fully qualify names.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can write the implementations in the header files. It's a really bad practice, though.