# unresolved external errors

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unresolved-external, lnk2019, lnk2005

I have the following .h and .cpp files

If i have to I will include the full codes of the function definitions

When i compile my program i get the errors shown at the end

hash.h

```
    #define BUCKETS 64
       #define B_ENTRIES 50000
       int curr_tanker;
       typedef unsigned long int ulong;
typedef struct bucket
{
    int bucket_id;
    ulong bucket_entries;
}bucket;

typedef struct tanker_record
{
    ulong tanker_id;
    ulong tanker_size;
    ulong num_of_entries;
    ulong bucket_entry_count;
   }tanker_record;
typedef struct fpinfo
{ 
    unsigned long chunk_offset;
    unsigned long chunk_length;
    unsigned char fing_print[33];

}fpinfo;

struct fpinfo* InitHTable(fpinfo *);
int CreateTanker(tanker_record tr[]);
int Hash_CreateEntry(struct fpinfo *,struct fpinfo he,tanker_record tr);
```

ht.cpp

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "ht.h"

struct fpinfo* InitHTable(struct fpinfo ht[][B_ENTRIES])
{
}
int CreateTanker(tanker_record tr[])
{
}
int
Hash_CreateEntry(struct fpinfo *t[][B_ENTRIES],struct fpinfo he,tanker_record tr[])
{
}
static void
WriteHTtoFile(struct fpinfo *t[][B_ENTRIES],int this_tanker)
{
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include"ht.cpp"
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
static fpinfo hash_table[BUCKETS][B_ENTRIES];
static tanker_record tr[100];
InitHTable(&hash_table[0][0]);
CreateTanker(tr);
struct fpinfo fp;
... 
ar = Hash_CreateEntry(&hash_table[0][0], fp,tr[0]);
```

i get the following errors when i try to compile it using vc2010

> 1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "struct fpinfo * __cdecl InitHTable(struct  fpinfo (* const)[50000])" (?InitHTable@@YAPAUfpinfo@@QAY0MDFA@U1@@Z) already defined in ht.obj
>
> 1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "int __cdecl CreateTanker(struct tanker_record * const)"
>   (?CreateTanker@@YAHQAUtanker_record@@@Z) already defined in ht.obj
>
> 1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "int __cdecl Hash_CreateEntry(struct fpinfo * (* const)[50000],struct fpinfo,struct tanker_record * const)" (?Hash_CreateEntry@@YAHQAY0MDFA@PAUfpinfo@@U1@QAUtanker_record@@@Z) already defined in ht.obj
>   1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "int curr_tanker" (?curr_tanker@@3HA) already defined in ht.obj
>   1>main.obj  : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl Hash_CreateEntry(struct fpinfo *,struct fpinfo,struct tanker_record)"
>   (?Hash_CreateEntry@@YAHPAUfpinfo@@U1@Utanker_record@@@Z) referenced in function _main 
>   1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct fpinfo * __cdecl InitHTable(struct fpinfo *)" (?InitHTable@@YAPAUfpinfo@@PAU1@@Z) referenced in function _main

THANKS FOR YOUR HELP!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're including `ht.cpp` from `main.cpp`, which will include all the definitions of functions already defined in `ht.cpp` itself.

You want to include `ht.h` instead.

It won't help in this situation, but you should also protect the header file with include guards:

```
#ifndef HT_H
#define HT_H

// contents of ht.h

#endif
```

You also need the arguments of the function declarations to match those of the definitions:

```
struct fpinfo* InitHTable(struct fpinfo[][B_ENTRIES]);
// Missing:                              ^^^^^^^^^^^

int CreateTanker(tanker_record tr[]); // OK

int Hash_CreateEntry(struct fpinfo*[][B_ENTRIES],struct fpinfo,tanker_record[]);
// Missing                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^                            ^^
```

Comment: that was what i did originally but it still gives the last three errors. It only avoids the first two "lnk2005" errors

Comment: @John: Oh yes, my eyes must have glazed over as I read the errors. That's because the declarations don't match the definitions - the declarations have pointer-to-object arguments, while the definitions have pointer-to-array arguments.

Comment: Thanks. But what would be the right syntax for the function calls? The first ones create errors **error C2664: 'InitHTable' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'fpinfo *' to 'fpinfo *[][50000]'** and **error C2664: 'Hash_CreateEntry' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'fpinfo *' to 'fpinfo *[][50000]'**

Comment: @John: It looks like it should be something like `Hash_CreateEntry(hash_table,fp,tr);`. It's hard to be sure though; the extra `*` in the function definition seems to imply that `hash_table` should be a 2-dimensional array of pointers, not of objects.

Comment: i got another problem. It says the function **WriteHTtoFile() is declared but not defined** what could be the problem? I guess it is some kind of argument type mismatch but no matter how hard i look at it i couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @John: I guess it's being called from one of the other functions in that file. Functions have to be declared (or defined) before they are called - either move the definition of that file above the other functions, or put a declaration above them.

Answer (score 1):

Add an "include guard" in your header, so that it its contents aren't "seen" twice after preprocessing. For Microsoft, `#pragma once` at the beginning of the .h file. In general, add:

```
#ifndef __YOUR_HEADER_H
#define __YOUR_HEADER_H
// all the stuff from the header here
#endif
```

Make sure to adopt a consistent "unique" naming scheme for each of your headers. `__YOUR_HEADER_H` would do, for example `customio.h` into `__CUSTOM_IO_H`.

Comment: Good idea, but you shouldn't use a [reserved name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783), in case [this happens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345159).

Comment: When i did as you said I get **error C2337: 'variable_name' : attribute not found** for all the variables used in ht.cpp

Comment: That, because you define storage in your header. Headers should only be for declarations, at most for constants. Always declare storage - put ``extern int curr_tanker;`` in the header and put the proper ``int curr_tanker;`` in the "implementation" .cpp file.