# C++ is not a namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

I don't really know how to explain this.

I have 2 classes World and Entity in the namespace:

> artemis::system;

and one class Component in

> artemis::component;

I already had trouble with World and Entity, when trying compile it said either one of them wasn't a declared type. ( they both include each other)
So in both classes, within the the namespace, I've added a forward declaration. This seems to solve the problem.

Now when I try to include "world" in my Component.h it gives me the following error:

> component is not a namespace-name

My Component class resides within the namespace artemis::component.

This is driving me crazy. I really don't get what is causing this error.

Header Component.h

```
#ifndef _COMPONENT_H_
#define _COMPONENT_H_

#include <bitset>
#include "BitSize.h"
#include "World.h"
#include <unordered_map>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
//#include "EntityManager.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace artemis::system;

namespace artemis {
    namespace component {


        class Component {
            public:
                virtual ~Component() = 0;
            protected:
                Component(){};
        };


        /**
         * Identifies a bitset and id for a component object
         * Do not instantiate a ComponentType, instead use the ComponentTypeManager.
         * */
        class ComponentType {

            public:
                ComponentType();

                bitset<BITSIZE> getBit() const;
                int getId() const;
            private:

                static bitset<BITSIZE> nextBit;
                static int nextId;

                bitset<BITSIZE> bit;
                int id;
                void init();

        };


//Surpress unused variable warnning. Might need to rewrite it
//#pragma GCC diagnostic push
//#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored  "-Wunused-variable"
        /**
         * Manages the id and bitset for every component based on their type.
         * */

        class ComponentTypeManager {

            private:
                ComponentTypeManager();
                static unordered_map<size_t,ComponentType*> componentTypes;



        public:


                /**
                 *
                 **/
                static ComponentType & getTypeFor(const type_info &t);

                /**
                * Gets the component type object
                **/
                template<typename c>
                static ComponentType & getTypeFor() {

                    //Check if we are being legal with components and shizzle
                    //Component * c = (component*)0;

                    assert((std::is_base_of< Component, c >::value == true));

                    return getTypeFor(typeid(c));
                }

                /**
                * Gets the bit set of a component
                **/
                template<typename c>
                static bitset<BITSIZE> getBit() {

                    //Check if we are being legal with components and shizzle
                    //Component * c = (component*)0;

                    assert((std::is_base_of< Component, c >::value == true));

                    ComponentType & type = getTypeFor(typeid(c));
                    return type.getBit();
                }
                /**
                 * Gets the component id
                 **/
                template<typename c>
                static int getId() {

                    //Check if we are being legal with components and shizzle

                    assert((std::is_base_of< Component, c >::value == true));

                    ComponentType & type = getTypeFor(typeid(c));
                    return type.getId();
                };



                //typedef getCompBit bitset<BITSIZE>(*getBit<Component>)();

        };
//#pragma GCC diagnostic pop




        /*template<typename T>
        class ComponentMapper {

            private:
                //ComponentType * type;
                EntityManager * em;

            public:

                ComponentMapper(World &world) {
                    em = world.getEntityManager();
                    //type = ComponentTypeManager::getTypeFor<T>();
                }

                ~ComponentType() {
                    type = nullptr;
                    em = nullptr;
                }

                T & get(Entity * e) {
                    return &(T)em->getComponent<T>(e);
                }

        };*/

    };
};

#endif
```

Header Entity.h

```
#ifndef _ENTITY_H
#define _ENTITY_H

#include <bitset>
#include <string>
#include <cstddef>
#include <typeinfo>
#include "BitSize.h"
#include "Component.h"
#include "ImmutableBag.h"
#include "World.h"
//#include "EntityManager.h"

using namespace artemis::util;
using namespace artemis::component;
//using namespace artemis;
using namespace std;



namespace artemis {
    namespace system {
        class World;
        class Entity {

            private:
                int id;
                long int uniqueId;
                bitset<BITSIZE> typeBits;
                bitset<BITSIZE> systemBits;
                World * world;
                //EntityManager * entityManager;
            protected:

            public:
                Entity(World * world, int id);
                ~Entity();
                int getID();
                void setUniqueId(long int uniqueId);
                long int getUniqueID();

                bitset<BITSIZE> getTypeBits();
                void addTypeBit(bitset<BITSIZE> bit);
                void removeTypeBit(bitset<BITSIZE> bit);
                bitset<BITSIZE> getSystemBits();
                void addSystemBit(bitset<BITSIZE> bit);
                void removeSystemBit(bitset<BITSIZE> bit);
                void setSystemBits(bitset<BITSIZE> systemBits);
                void setTypeBits(bitset<BITSIZE> typeBits);
                void reset();

                string toString();

                void addComponent(Component * c);

                //Might change to non template
                template<typename c>
                void removeComponent() {
                    //entityManager->removeComponent(this,ComponentTypeManager::getTypeFor<c>());
                }

                void removeComponent(ComponentType & type);
                bool isActive();

                Component * getComponent(ComponentType & type);

                /*template<typename c>
                Component * getComponent() {
                    return (c)entityManager->getComponent(ComponentTypeManager.getTypeFor<c>());
                }*/

                ImmutableBag<Component*> * getComponents();
                void refresh();
                void remove();
                void setGroup(string group);
                void setTag(string tag);


        };
    };
};
#endif // $(Guard token)
```

Header World.h

```
#ifndef _WORLD_H_
#define _WORLD_H_

//#include "SystemManager.h"
//#include "EntityManager.h"
#include "ImmutableBag.h"
#include "Entity.h"

using namespace artemis::util;



namespace artemis {
    namespace system {

    class Entity;

        class World {
            public:
                World();
                ~World();
                //SystemManager * getSystemManager();
                //EntityManager * getEntityManager();
                //TagManager *   getTagManager();
                //GroupManager * getGroupManager();
                int getDelta();
                void setDetla(int delta);
                void deleteEntity(Entity *e);
                void refreshEntity(Entity *e);
                //Entity* createEntity();
                //Entity* getEntity(int entityID);
                void loopStart();



            private:
                //SystemManager * systemManager;
                //EntityManager * entityManager;
                //TagManager * tagManager;
                //GroupManager * grouManager;
                int delta;
                Bag<Entity*> refreshed;
                Bag<Entity*> deleted;



        };
    };
};
#endif // $(Guard token)
```

Comment: What do you mean by testcase?

Comment: Sounds like you are confusing a namespace with the type name.  Is component *actually* a namespace or is it a type?

Comment: Testcase is what I mean by testcase... Google would tell you what that means, as well as http://sscce.org/...

Comment: @EdS.

I've teste Component before I created the World and entity class. I had no trouble with the namespace component. Are capitals ignored?

Comment: "*when trying compile it said either one of them wasn't a declared type. ( they both include each other)*" Sounds like a circular inclusion problem, not a namespace problem. Show us your header files.

Comment: I've added the headers. Runs fine if I take out the "World.h" from Component.h

Comment: `Component.h` includes `World.h`, `World.h` includes `Entity.h`, `Entity.h` includes `Component.h` and `World.h` -- _that_ is your problem, not namespaces. Read up on forward declarations and get rid of the circular inclusion.

Comment: fyi, it's usually not a good idea to put a `using namespace ...;` statement in a header file.

Comment: It's also a bad idea to use reserved names for include guards.

Comment: @MikeSeymour which names are reserved?

Comment: @Sidar: Anything that begins with an underscore followed by a capital letter, or that contains a double underscore; also, anything in the global namespace that begins with an underscore. So `_COMPONENT_H_` shouldn't begin with `_`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/204847) for full details, and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3345159/204847) for an example of what might go wrong if you break the rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you require `Component` to already be defined in order to create `World`, and you require `World` to be defined in order to create `Component`.  This is impossible; each one's definition requires the other.

You need to restructure your classes so that you either don't require `Component` to be defined in `World`'s header, OR you don't require `World` to be define in `Component`'s header.  You can always include them in the .cpp, but not the header.  It's a circular inclusion problem.  You could also forward-declare one of the classes.

You are essentially saying: I cannot create `A` unless I have already created `B`; I cannot create `B` unless I have already created `A`.  That's impossible, and the compiler is telling you so.

Comment: I figured that much, but they both need eachother. And some types are also used in the header. Wouldn't that go wrong if I put the inclusion in the cpp? NVM.

Comment: Yes, it would go wrong.  If they are absolutely required in the header, you can forward-declare the classes. Take a look at this link: http://www-subatech.in2p3.fr/~photons/subatech/soft/carnac/CPP-INC-1.shtml