# reference to pointer not working on header files in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, pass-by-reference, forward-declaration

When I use *& reference in header files it gives me a error

```
void free_memory_circle( Node  *& root );

error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘&’ token
```

I have a working liked list file with all the functions in a one file and when I try to separate them into .h and .cc files I cannot use *& reference pointer. Would someone explain me the reason.

my header file edited

```
#ifndef _EX4A_FREEMEMORY_H_
#define _EX4A_FREEMEMORY_H_

#include "BST.h"


void free_memory_circle( Node  *&root );
void free_memory_rectangle( Node  *&root );



#endif  // FreeMemory.h
```

my code file

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include "FreeMemory.h"
#include "Circle.h"
#include "Rectangle.h"

void free_memory_circle( Node  *&root )
{
    if( root == NULL ) return;
    free_memory_circle( root->_left );
    free_memory_circle( root->_right );
    delete( (Circle * )root->data);
    delete ( root);

}

void free_memory_rectangle( Node  *&root )
{
    if( root == NULL ) return;

    free_memory_rectangle( root->_left );
    free_memory_rectangle( root->_right );
    delete( (Rectangle * )root->data);
    delete ( root);

}
```

BST.h file

```
#ifndef _EX4A_BST_H_
#define _EX4A_BST_H_
#include "Circle.h" 
#include "Rectangle.h"

typedef struct Node
{
    void *data;
    struct Node *_left, *_right;
} Node ;

extern double max_radius;   //saves maximum radius
extern double max_area_rect;    //saves maximum area of rectangles
extern Node *BST_circles ;
extern Node *BST_rectangles ;

//this is a similar to linked list(binary search tree)
//so I have to use *& here for head node
//void add_circle_BST( Node *& root , Circle *p );
void add_circle_BST( Node * root , Circle *p );
void PrintBST_circle_inorder( Node *root );
void add_rectangle_BST( Node *root , Rectangle *p );
void PrintBST_Rectangle_inorder( Node *root );
void find_max_radius( Node *root);
void find_max_area_rect( Node *root);

#endif  // BST.h
```

BST.cc file

```
#include<iostream>
#include "BST.h"
#include "Rectangle.h"
#include "Circle.h"

using namespace std;

double max_radius = 0;  //saves maximum radius
double max_area_rect = 0;   //saves maximum area of rectangles

Node *BST_circles = NULL;
Node *BST_rectangles = NULL;

//this is a similar to linked list(binary search tree)
//so I have to use *& here for head node
void add_circle_BST( Node *&root , Circle *p )
{
    //root = BST_circles;
    if( !root ) //IF root is null
    {
        root = new Node;
        root->data = p;
    }else{
            Circle *temp = (Circle *)root->data;
            if( temp->_x > p->_x){  //if x value less than root x                
            add_circle_BST(root->_left , p); //add to left
    }else{
            add_circle_BST( root->_right , p);
    }
}
}

void PrintBST_circle_inorder( Node *root )
{
if( root ){
    PrintBST_circle_inorder( root->_left);
    Circle *temp = (Circle *)root->data;
    cout << temp->_x << " " << temp->_y << " "
            << temp->_r << endl;
    PrintBST_circle_inorder( root->_right);

}

}


void add_rectangle_BST( Node *root , Rectangle *p )
{
if( !root ){    //IF root is null
    root = new Node;
    root->data = p;
}else { //
    Rectangle *temp = (Rectangle *)root->data;
    if( temp->_top_left_x > p->_top_left_x)//if x value less than root x
    {
        add_rectangle_BST(root->_left , p); //add to left
    }
    else
    {
        add_rectangle_BST( root->_right , p);
    }
}
}


void PrintBST_Rectangle_inorder( Node *root )
{
if( root )
{
    PrintBST_Rectangle_inorder( root->_left);
    Rectangle *temp = (Rectangle *)root->data;
    cout << temp->_top_left_x << " " << temp->_top_left_y << " "
            << temp->_bot_right_x << " " << temp->_bot_right_y << endl;
    PrintBST_Rectangle_inorder( root->_right);

}

}



void find_max_radius( Node *root)
{
if( root ){ //IF root is null
    Circle *temp = (Circle *)root->data;
    if( max_radius < temp->_r )
    {
        max_radius = temp->_r;
    }
    find_max_radius(root->_left ); //add to left
    find_max_radius( root->_right);

}
}

void find_max_area_rect( Node *root)
{
if( root ){ //IF root is null
    Rectangle *temp = (Rectangle *)root->data;
    if( max_area_rect < Area_rect( temp ) )
    {
        max_area_rect = Area_rect( temp );
    }
    find_max_area_rect(root->_left ); //add to left
    find_max_area_rect( root->_right);

}
}
```

Circle.h

```
#ifndef _EX4A_CIRCLE_H_
#define _EX4A_CIRCLE_H_


typedef struct Circle{
    double _x,_y,_r;
} Circle;

#endif  // Circle.h
```

FreeMemory.h

```
#ifndef _EX4A_FREEMEMORY_H_
#define _EX4A_FREEMEMORY_H_

#include "BST.h"

void free_memory_circle( Node  *&root );
void free_memory_rectangle( Node  *&root );

#endif  // FreeMemory.h
```

Comment: Sounds like you're missing a declaration of the Node type.

Comment: I edited I have the declaration on header file. I can compile .cc file without any issue. But header file gives me a error.

Comment: The problematic declaration does not appear in the posted header file text.

Comment: We dont see `free_memory_circle` in your header. Please show all the relevant code.

Comment: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘&’ token 
When I try to compile .h file

Comment: In my BST header file also I need to add *&

Comment: @quantdev added relevant files, because you ask for other files I think this not a normal error and I have messed something in the code ?

Comment: It's probably not causing your problem, but using [reserved names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783) like `_EX4A_BST_H_` for include guards (or for anything else) is [asking for trouble](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345159).

Comment: checked your compiler switches? Are you compiling C++ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We still don't have all your header files, but I'm guessing that `Circle.h` includes `FreeMemory.h`, causing the problematic declaration to be parsed before the declaration of `struct Node`.

You can break the circular dependency (if there really is one) with a forward declaration of `Node` instead of including `BST.h`, from which you only need this one small item.

```
// #include "BST.h" <= remove this

struct Node; // Introduce Node as a placeholder, or "incomplete class."

void free_memory_circle( Node  *&root );
void free_memory_rectangle( Node  *&root );
```

Comment: Thank you. I managed to solve it. There was a issue with forward declaration and also my **IDE was messing with header files that it was compiling them with gcc and .cc files by g++.** . Sorry I can't vote you, because I have less reputation.

Comment: You shouldn't be compiling header files by themself at all (unless you're talking about precompiled headers)

Comment: @KrvPerera You should click the checkmark icon (below the vote arrows) if this solved your problem.