# Did `#pragma once` make it into C++0x?

Tags: c++, c++11, c-preprocessor, pragma

The title says it all. Have `#pragma once` been standardized for C++0x? I don't know any compiler that doesn't provide an implementation of it, with almost always the same semantics and name.

Comment: See this for a [gotcha in `#pragma once`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787533/is-pragma-once-a-safe-include-guard/1946730#1946730)

Comment: "Almost"? You're fine using it in different compilers that don't treat it identically? Or, what other names do you know it by? (It's unclear to which one the "almost" applies, or both?)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All `#pragma` directives cause the implementation to behave in an implementation defined way.

This hasn't changed between C++03 and the latest C++0x draft (n3225.pdf). Include guards are the portable alternative.

Comment: I know that guards are the portable alternative but I thought it could have been standardized anyway.

Comment: Note that the latest draft is n3225.pdf.

Comment: @Prasoon: So it is. In my defence, the "current draft" on the WG21 web page is not up to date. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/

Comment: Ok, `#pragma once` can cause problems, but I wonder - why not considering other alternatives, for example `#pragma once ID`, with a user-specified ID? Or am I the only to be disgusted by those copy-pasted ifdef-define-endif lines?..

Comment: If a kind of #pragma once become standard, that don't forces you to use it on all files, so I don't see the prolem with adding it to the standard (other than giving it a non-pragma name).

Comment: @Klaim: Mostly just because it's completely unnecessary to add that to the language. It can already be done with the features already in the language.

Answer (score 6):

Sun C++ compiler (Solaris) does not implement it. And no, it's not in C++0x drafts.

Answer (score -2):

It's also trivial to implement using #ifdef. What's the guiding principal for the new version? Implement everything you might ever want and the kitchen sink or just give you the minimum tools to do so yourself?

Comment: You're missing the point. A big part of sandardisation is to make common practice be the minimal available for standard-compliant tools. As `#pragma once` IS provided by a lot of compilers and has been proved useful. A keyword equivalent standardized would have been helpful.

Comment: include guards force you to choose names in the (one and only global) preprocessor namespace. which is a pain. granted, most projects need macros somewhere, so they have deal with the issue of choosing preprocessor identifiers without causing collisions anyway. nevertheless it's a pain, and the i still see a lot of #ifdef FILENAME_H code flying around. which is ARGH. most sensible projects use PROJECTNAME_FILENAME_SOMESUFFIX, which is OKish, but well... . IMO #pragma once is just the better solution.