# C++ inherit class shows no default constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm creating a few classes and I decided to create a basic class that other classes will just inherit that basic class

So here is my basic class header

```
#pragma once

#include "ImageService.h"

class State
{
public:
    State( ImageService& is );
    ~State();

    void Update();

};
```

don't worry about the methods, they aren't the problem.
So now I go ahead and create a IntroState like so (header file)

```
#pragma once

#include "State.h"

class IntroState : public State
{
public:
    IntroState(ImageService& imageService);
    ~IntroState();

    GameState objectState;
};
```

and here is the cpp file

```
#include "IntroState.h"


IntroState::IntroState(ImageService& imageService)
{
    //error here
}


IntroState::~IntroState()
{
}
```

at the constructor it is stating "no default constructor for class "State"", now what I think is going on is, the default constructor for State needs a imageService reference passed to it. So how would I pass the imageservice in this constructor to the state constructor?

Comment: +1 for nice formatting and actually, almost answering the question himself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your base class has no default constructor, which is what gets implicitly called in your current derived class constructor. You need to explicitly call the base's constructor:

```
IntroState::IntroState(ImageService& imageService) : State(imageService)
{

}
```

Comment: I literally just typed that and it worked :D, Cheers for the quick reply though

Answer (score 3):

The usual way:

```
IntroState::IntroState(ImageService& imageService)
    : State(imageService)
{
}
```

Comment: I literally just typed that and it worked :D, Cheers for the quick reply though

Answer (score 1):

You should call the constructor of `State` too, like this:

```
IntroState::IntroState(ImageService& imageService)
    : State(imageService) {
}
```

Tip: Don't use:

`#pragma once`, use guards!

Example:

```
#ifndef GRANDFATHER_H
#define GRANDFATHER_H

class A {
    int member;
};

#endif /* GRANDFATHER_H */
```

You can read more about the include guards in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

You see [`#pragma`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787533/is-pragma-once-a-safe-include-guard) is **not standard**. Neither became in `C++11` ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563356/did-pragma-once-make-it-into-c0x)).