# Visual Studio 2008 class view missing classes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, vs-classview

I've just ported a large project from an older version of Visual C++ to VS2008 and notice that the class view is mising a bunch of my classes.  Looking at the solution view, the header files declaring those classes are present, so I'd expect to see them in class view.  Any reason why certain classes would be excluded, or is there any way to refresh class view to include all the classes in the solution ?

Comment: IntelliSense parser failure is silent.  Working backwards from the classes that you don't see ought to give a hint where it gave up the ghost.  It was completely rewritten for VS2010, much improved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tried Hans' suggestion of looking what was different about a header file with a missing class, and noticed the following

**myheader.h**

```
#ifndef MYHEADER_INCLUDED
#define MYHEADER_INCLUDED

class MyClass 
{ 
'
'
};

#endif
```

Now everything after the #ifdef was greyed out in the editor, which suggested the IDE throught the macro was already defined.  The source also contains a fair amount of conditional inclusion in the header files, e.g.

```
#ifndef MYHEADER_INCLUDED
#include "myheader.h"
#endif
```

Changing the header to

**myheader.h**

```
#pragma once

class MyClass 
{ 
'
'
};
```

seems to resolve the class view problem, though I don't know how it will effect compilation times.

**Edit**  Just finished and did a rebuild, no significant change to compilation time.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried deleting the .ncb and the .pch, and all the .o files, then a full rebuild? I find that this often fixes my intellisense problems, and it may be related.