# eclipse's auto-generated .h file guards

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

In eclipse, when a c++ class is created, .h file's auto-generated with guard `XXXX_H_`. In my limited, little experience, the guard is always be in the form of  `XXXX_H` without the trailing `_`.

So, I'm just curious and wondering why the `_` is over there.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trailing `_` might be added to avoid collision with user-defined identifiers. For example, you might have a header file named `get.h` and at the same time you can conceivably have your own macro (or variable, or function) named `GET_H`. So, using `GET_H` for include guard in `get.h` would easily lead to problems.

The standard library header files might use a leading `_` to name its internal macros for the very same purpose - to avoid name collision with user-defined identifiers. For that reason, the language specification explicitly prohibits user-defined identifiers that begin with `_` and a capital letter. And for the very same reason, the *leading* `_` cannot be used in the names of include guards.

So, Eclipse decided to use a *trailing* `_` for the very same purpose. It provides a reasonable level of protection from name collisions and does not violate the requirements of language specification.

Answer (score 4):

If you use a reasonably modern compiler, you can replace these guards with more elegant directive `#pragma once`

To modify the header's template in Eclipse CDT, go to "Window/Preferences/C++/Code Templates/Files/C++ Header File/Default C++ header template" and put there

```
${filecomment}

#pragma once

${typecomment}
${declarations}
```

After that your new h files will start from something like this:

```
/*
 * FileServer.h
 *
 *  Created on: Feb 26, 2011
 *      Author: krit
 */

#pragma once
```

Comment: #pragma once is elegant, except when it doesn't work! <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787533/is-pragma-once-a-safe-include-guard>

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: Check the answer with the highest score - #pragma once is fine, except when it doesn't work. Sometimes the compiler cannot tell if two files are the same or different. Then what happens?

Comment: So far I've only found that prior to version 3.4 GCC didn't recognize some specific cases, such as symbolic and hard links. It was fixed long time ago. That's why I was asking if there's anything else that should be considered.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter what the name of the inclusion guard is, so long as it is unique across all header files.

`XXXX_H_` is common, as is `XXXX_H`.  GUIDs are occasionally used.

Answer (score 1):

The name is irrelevant, it just needs to be unique. My guess is that it was added to make it less likely to have a collision with user-created defines.