# Circular references in C++ in different files

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

If i want a circular reference but in two different files in C++, how would I implement that?

For example

AUnit.h

```
#inclue <BUnit.h>
class AClass : public TObject
{

   __published
        BClass * B;
};
```

BUnit.h

```
#include <AUnit.h>
class BClass : public TObject
{
    __published
        AClass *A;     
};
```

I can't make it in only one file with forward declarations.

Comment: You probably refer to "cyclic reference" rather than "dual reference", and for that you need a forward declaration of one or the other.

Comment: what is a dual reference ? what is the meaning of keyword `__published`?

Comment: #pragma once (or #ifndef guards) - the topic elaborated on here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787533/is-pragma-once-a-safe-include-guard

Comment: @holtavolt: That would not solve the problem, which is that the compiler needs to "see" `AClass` before the `BClass` declaration, and vice versa.

Comment: @Oli: I see - misread the question.  Yes, forward declaration needed, as @dribeas mentions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're talking about *circular dependencies*.

The answer is indeed to use a forward declaration, such as:

**AUnit.h**

```
#include <BUnit.h>
class AClass : public TObject
{
   BClass *B;
};
```

**BUnit.h**

```
class AClass;  // Forward declaration

class BClass : public TObject
{
   AClass *A;
};
```

You could even have a forward declaration in *both* header files, if you wanted.

Answer (score 6):

You can use forward declaration in this case too:

```
// AUnit.h
class BClass;
class AClass : public TObject
{

   __published
        BClass * B;
};
```

---

```
// BUnit.h
#include <AUnit.h>
class BClass : public TObject
{
    __published
        AClass *A;     
};
```

There is no difference to the scenario if they are both in one file, because `#include` does nothing but inserting the included file (it is really jut text-replacement). It is exactly the same. After preprocessing of `BUnit.h`, the above will look like this:

```
class BClass;

class AClass : public TObject
{

   __published
        BClass * B;
};

class BClass : public TObject
{
    __published
        AClass *A;     
};
```

Comment: There aren't any solutions in two different files? Another method is to declare one of them an object and to use dynamic_cast

Comment: @user558126, you can have forward declarations in a two-file solution.