# Include guard style, C++

Tags: c++, coding-style, include-guards

I have a .h file which contains several class definitions. I'd like to use C++'s include guards in this file; however, I was wondering which way of using the include guards is considered proper/correct?

One guard protecting everything

```
#ifndef FOO_BAR
#define FOO_BAR

class Foo
{
};

class Bar
{      
};

#endif
```

or multiple separate guards.

```
#ifndef FOO
#define FOO

class Foo
{
};

#endif

#ifndef BAR
#define BAR

class Bar
{      
};

#endif
```

Comment: One is enough. Both classes should only be defined once, which happens to anything inside the guard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are include guards, preventing double inclusion of **files**. So they should be defined once per file, not per class or function or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered to use #pragma once ? Most modern compilers support it.

[Is #pragma once a safe include guard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787533/is-pragma-once-a-safe-include-guard)