# including a header file twice in c++

Tags: c++, header-files

What happens if I include `iostream` or any other header file twice in my file?
I know the compiler does not throw error.

Will the code gets added twice or what happens internally?

What actually happens when we include a header file ?

Comment: Great help:: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10627/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[Include guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) prevents the content of the file from being actually seen twice by the compiler.

Include guard is basically a set of preprocessor's conditional directives at the beginning and end of a header file:

```
#ifndef SOME_STRING_H
#define SOME_STRING_H

//...

#endif
```

Now if you include the file twice then first time round macro `SOME_STRING_H` is not defined and hence the contents of the file is processed and seen by the compiler. However, since the first thing after `#ifdef` is `#define`, `SOME_STRING_H` is defined and the next time round the header file's content is not seen by the compiler.

To avoid collisions the name of the macro used in the include guard is made dependent on the name of the header file.

Comment: Just a note: When using Microsoft tools you will often see a `#pragma once`, which has the same functinality like the `#ifndef...`. For better compiler compatibility you should use the latter.

Comment: Note too that most compilers will recognize this pattern, and not even open the file when it sees it a second time.

Comment: This does not actually answer the question. I'm interested in the original question because I'm looking at someone else's code.

Comment: That's very stupid compiler, I'd say.

Answer (score 5):

Header files are simple beasts. When you `#include <header>` all that happens is that the contents of `header` basically get copy-pasted into the file. To stop headers from being included multiple times, `include guards` are used, which is why in most header files you'll see something akin to

```
#ifndef SOME_HEADER_FILE_GUARD 
#define SOME_HEADER_FILE_GUARD

//Contents of Header

#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends.  With the exception of `<assert>`, the standard requires the
second (and later) includes of a standard header to be a no-op.  This is
a characteristic of the header, however; the compiler will (at least
conceptually) read and include all of the header text each time it
encounters the include.

The standard practice for avoiding multiple definitions in such cases is
to use include guards: all of the C++ code in the header will be
enclosed in something like:

```
#ifndef SPECIAL_NAME
#define SPECIAL_NAME
//  All of the C++ code here
#endif SPECIAL_NAME
```

Obviously, each header needs a different name.  Within an application,
you can generally establish conventions based on the filename and
location; something like `subsystem_filename`, with
characters not legal in a C++ symbol (if you're using them in your
filenames) mapped (and very often everything upper cased).  For
libraries, the best practice would be to generate a reasonably long
random sequence of characters; far more frequent (although certainly
inferior from a quality of implementation standpoint) is to ensure that
every such symbol begin with a documented prefix.

A system library can, of course, use reserved symbols (e.g. a symbol
starting with an underscore followed by a capital letter) here, to
guarantee that there is no conflict.  Or it can use some entirely
different, implementation dependent technique.  Microsoft, for example,
uses a compiler extension `#pragma once`; g++ uses include guards which
always start with `_GLIBCXX` (which isn't a legal symbol in user code).
These options aren't necessarily available to you.

Answer (score 2):

It simply gets skipped over, due to preprocessor code along the following lines:

```
#ifndef MY_HEADER_H
#define MY_HEADER_H

<actual header code here>

#endif
```

So if you include twice, then `MY_HEADER_H` is already defined and everything between the `#ifndef` and `#endif` is skipped by the preprocessor.

Answer (score 2):

When you include a header file, all its contents get copied to the line where the "#include" directive was placed. This is done by the preprocessor and is a step in the compilation process.

This process is the same for standard files like iostream or user-made ".h" files stored in local directory. However, the syntax slightly differs.

We use `#include <filename>` for files like 'iostream' which are stored in the library. Whereas, for header files in the local directory, we use `#include "filename.h"`.

**Now, what if we include header files twice:**

Ideally speaking the content should be copied twice. But...

1. Many header files use the modern practice of mentioning `#pragma once` which instructs the pre-processor to copy contents only once, no matter how many times the header file is included.
2. Some very old codes use a concept called 'include gaurds'. I won't explain it as the other answers do so very well.

Using `pragma once` is the easy and the modern approach, however, include guards were used a lot previously and is a relatively complicated fix to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure when it was introduced, but **instead of** for instance:

```
#ifndef SOME_STRING_H
#define SOME_STRING_H

//...

#endif
```

Since I felt sometimes on `SOME_STRING_H` being already define in a lib I used or quite same header in a different namespace, **I prefer using**:

```
#pragma once

// ...

// Nothing to put at the end like #endif above
```

Comment: This pragma has been mentioned in several older answers. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787533/is-pragma-once-a-safe-include-guard it is not standard C++ although widely supported by compilers.