# Redefinition of struct g++

Tags: c++, header, g++

So, I'm working on a project and I have a header file `simpleCommand.hh` that I need to reference in two other headers. I have included `simpleCommand.hh` in `command.hh` and `builtin.hh`. Now, `builtin.hh` is included in `command.cc` which also includes `command.hh`, so g++ is telling me that the `struct SimpleCommand` is being defined twice. However, if I remove `simpleCommand.hh` include from `builtin.hh`, g++ tells me that `SimpleCommand` hasn't been defined when I use it in `builtin.hh`.

Here's the weird part: if after doing all this, I go into `builtin.hh` and re-add `include "simpleCommand.hh"`, the program compiles fine. However, randomly if I try to compile at another point in the future, g++ will give me this error again and I have to start the process over.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: You should have header guards in your header files, so that including them a second time is ignored.

Comment: Use include guards in your header file. Learn them here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928919/including-a-header-file-twice-in-c

Comment: Sorry, I neglected to mention that all the header files have the
`#ifndef
#define
...
#endif`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you juste need to delete SimpleCommand.hh from command.hh because build.hh get it and command.hh herited to build.hh so command.hh will get SimpleCommand.hh twice. Or you can declare some of function of SimpleCommand.hh as virtual     :)