# Using friend function in C++

Tags: c++, class, friend, friend-class

Just read about friend functions and I'm trying to access private variable "number" in class A with friend function "Print" from class B. I'm working with Visual Studio. Compilation of my code gives me plenty of various errors like:

> C2011: 'A' : 'class' type redefinition
>   C2653: 'B' : is not a class or namespace name

Please be patient with me me and show a proper way of achieving my goal.

Here are my files
A.h:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int a);
    friend void B::Print(A &obj);
private:
    int number;
};
```

A.cpp:

```
#include "A.h"

A::A(int a)
{
    number=a;
}
```

B.h:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "A.h"
class B
{
public:
    B(void);
    void Print(A &obj);
};
```

B.cpp:

```
#include "B.h"

B::B(void){}

void B::Print(A &obj)
{
    cout<<obj.number<<endl;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "B.h"
#include "A.h"

void main()
{
    A a_object(10);
    B b_object;
    b_object.Print(A &obj);
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: tip: class `B` doesn't actually need to know the details of `A`, all it needs to know is that class `A` _exists_.

Comment: remove `friend void B::Print(A &obj);`, add `friend class B;` or follow Mooning Ducks tip.

Comment: In B.h remove 
`#include "A.h"`
and add 
`class A;` then add `#include "A.h"` in B.cpp

Answer (score 3):

... Second you might need a forward declaration of class `B` in the `A.h` header file to refer `B` as a friend:

```
#ifndef _A_H_
#define _A_H_
class B;

class A
{
     friend class B;
};
#endif
```

**UPDATE**
<strike>I'm currently not so sure if it's possible to declare member functions as friends, I'll have a look.</strike>

It's not possible to create member function `friend` declarations, you can either declare global functions or whole classes as friend, see also: [C++ ref, Friendship and inheritance](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/).

In general it's not a good design idea to use `friend` at all, because it strongly couples the classes together. The better solution will be to couple interfaces (which don't need to be publicly visible anyways).
In rare cases it might be a good design decision but that almost always applies to internal details.

Comment: Using `friend` isn't always bad. See http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/friends-and-encap.html

Comment: @FredLarson Yes, I mentioned that Fred. Anyway it's already deprecated in UML and you can usually replace the need for `friend` declarations using either abstract (pure virtual) or static (template) interfaces. This might also give you the fine grained control over what exactly can be accessed by a 'friend' class or method.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to put

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H
.... your A-class definition
#endif
```

in your A.h and analogous in B.h, so that multiple includes of the same file is prevented (that is your duplicate definition error)...

Comment: Or you can put "#pragma once" at the begining of your .h files.

Comment: No, please: remove the double underscores. Names that contain two underscores and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved to the implementation. Don't use them.

Comment: @PRouleau Hmm. If you are in the Visual C++-World. Not sure wether gcc understands that?

Comment: Well, the OP didn't mention the code should be portable and it does use Visual Studio. As for GCC, it does understand it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787533/is-pragma-once-a-safe-include-guard I prefer to use it because it is one line and have no chance to conflic with another header file.

Comment: I would add that the OP is starting with C++. Where should he learn that the #define with underscores are reserved? I searched "c++ #define" and it is not specified in its description. Of course, any good book or tutorial would mention the importance to use include guards, but not always about the reserved rules.