# Cannot reach a vector in a differend class using "Friend"

Tags: c++

I have 2 classes: `company` and `cpworker`.

Im trying to pass a vector in company to a function of `cpworker`, though when I try to reach the vector it doesn't let me:

In the `company` class:

```
vector<project> projects;
friend void cpworker::registerWork();
```

In the `cpworker` class:

```
void cpworker::registerWork()
{   
    for (int i = 0; i < company.projects.size(); i++)
    {

    }
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to reach the size of the vector, but it does not let me..
Also, I didn't use a `get` method to company to return the size of the projects, because I need a full access to it inside the loop.

Here are the errors I'm getting (all in the for loop line):

> `* left of .projects must have class/struct/union`
>   `* left of .size must have class/struct/union`
>   `* type name is not allowed`

Comment: From your **incomplete** definition, it seems you are trying to access  a member of an instance, without an instance. What is `company` inside `registerWork`? Is it the class name or an instance? what is the class name if it's an instance, than? What is the exact error you got?

Comment: what do you mean by doesn't let me. What is the error you get?

Comment: @izomorphius edited my post at the bottom...
@DimaRudnik ` company ` is a class, and `register work` is a method inside a differend class... I dont have any class or anything called `name`...

Comment: Is `company` in cpworker class a local member variable? From the information provided it is unclear what it is or where it comes from. Your error indicates the compiler has no clue wtf `company` is, and therefore the `.projects` can't find home.

Comment: May be this answer helps: [Using friend function in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884788/using-friend-function-in-c/13885064#13885064)

Comment: Then that's your problem. What is the name of the `company` member variable (or reference, whatever) in `cpworker` class? or is there even one at all??

Comment: @WhozCraig Im trying to pass the vector that is called projects into a method in cpworker.. and as I said above, I have both classes...

Comment: I still don't think you're getting it. You're not passing *anything* into `coworker::registerWork()`. You're trying to access a member variable of class `company`, friended or not, *with no instance of the class `company`*. If `projects` is static to `company` then use **`company::projects`** to access it.

Comment: Try to define a company class instance like "company theCompany" in cpworker class then try to access the with theCompany.projects

Comment: I did create an instance and tried to use it, yet it still gives me the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`company` is a class and unless projects is decalred static you can not access it without an instance of the class. Either create an instance or make projects static member.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I made ` projects` static, yet I still get the error when I try to use `company.projects.size() ` (same error)... I tried to make an instance, yet it still tells me the same error (for exmple. A.projects.size() )

Comment: static members are accessed via two coluns `company::projects`

Comment: Then can you write a short complete code sample so that I can see what is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to create member function `friend` declarations, you can either declare global functions or whole classes as friend, see also: [C++ ref, Friendship and inheritance](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/).

In general it's not a good design idea to use friend at all, because it strongly couples the classes together. The better solution will be to couple interfaces (which don't need to be publicly visible anyways).
In rare cases it might be a good design decision but that almost always applies to internal details.