# C++ friend functions

Tags: c++, friend, access-control, friend-function

My question is pretty simple. I'm learning about friend functions, but this does not work for some reason. It only words if i swap the screen class with the Window_Mgr class, and then add a forward declaration of the screen class. Does it not work because screen doesn't know of the existence of "Relocate" at that point in time?

```
class Window_Mgr;
class screen
{
public:
    typedef string::size_type index;
    friend Window_Mgr& Window_Mgr::relocate(int, int, screen&);
private:
    int width, height;
};

class Window_Mgr
{
public:
    Window_Mgr& relocate(int r, int c, screen& s);
private:

};

Window_Mgr& Window_Mgr::relocate(int r, int c, screen& s)
{
    s.height=10;
    s.width=10;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: What compiler error do you get?

Comment: You never call anything in `main()` what were you expecting?

Comment: Your guess is correct. It does not work because `screen` doesn't know of the existence of `Relocate` at that point in time.

Comment: IMHO you should avoid friend functions. Scott Myers has a good argument to this recourse.

Comment: You can't refer to members of a class until after they are declared. This is not specific to `friend`.

Comment: @AlokSave What do you mean calling in main()?

Comment: See also here: [Cannot reach a vector in a differend class using “Friend”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056389/cannot-reach-a-vector-in-a-differend-class-using-friend/14057008#14057008)

Answer (score 2):

You have to define the class `Window_Mgr` BEFORE `screen`, because in your code the compiler cannot make sure that `Window_Mgr` really has a member function with name `relocate`, OR you are simply lying to it. The compiler parses the file from top to bottom, and on the way down, it's job is to make sure that every declaration is a fact, not lie!

Since `relocate()` takes a parameter of type `screen&`, you've to provide the forward declaration of `screen` instead!

With these fixes, (and along with other minor ones) this code [compiles fine](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=0818550097decca404b3b3b9b5c695ef) now (ignore the silly warnings).

Comment: Is it worth mentioning that this is distinctly different from non-member functions, in which case the `friend` declaration also serves as a function declaration, which it cannot do for member functions (for obvious reasons)?

Comment: @JaredC: That is an interesting question. But it is not entirely different from non-member functions. The rule is more about *scope*, rather than member-ness of a function. I mean a friend from different namespace will have the same problem, e.g `friend void other_namespace::relocate(int, int, screen&);` is NOT a declaration. So if you have to provide the declaration before the class even in this case!

Comment: In the previous comment, I meant, *"[...] is NOT a **function** declaration."* It is a *friend* declaration though!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `Window_Mgr::relocate` is unknown at the time of the friend declaration. You have to define `Window_Mgr` beforehand.