# C++ 'string' does not name a type in header

Tags: c++

Eugh, 2 problems in one day. I am having one of those bad days you hear so much about. I have been organizing my small project to make it less cluttered. It's at the start of the development so there isn't much going on. I have this header below

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

class Game_Map
{
    private:
        int map_width;
        int map_height;
        string map_data [50][50]
    public:
        Game_Map(int default_width = 20,int default_height = 20)
        ~Game_Map()
};
```

Now as far as I can see, there shouldn't be any problems. I avoided using the "using" and I kept the programming up til now at the basic to prevent external interference. But am I 100% of the time getting "map.h:9:9: error: 'string' does not name a type"

I am certain I have missed something. Can anyone see where I have gone wrong?

Comment: `#pragma once` is non-portable. Use standard include guards instead.

Comment: Standard include guards?

Comment: `#ifndef GUARD_Game_Map\n#define GUARD_Game_Map\n/*Your code*/\n#endif`

Comment: Interesting. Do you have a tutorial/article on this attribute? I'd like to look into it

Comment: Just search for "include guards" on the web. Well, most modern compilers implement it. This post [Is #pragma once a safe include guard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787533/is-pragma-once-a-safe-include-guard) discusses it more.

Answer (score 9):

Change

```
string map_data [50][50]
```

to

```
std::string map_data [50][50];
```

That's necessary because string belongs to the std namespace.

Don't use "using" declaration or directive in a header file.

Answer (score 1):

Use either a fully qualified name (preferable) as

```
std::string map_data [50][50];
```

or use using declaration

```
using std::string;
string map_data [50][50];
```

or using directive

```
using namespace std;
string map_data [50][50]'
```

Comment: @Massa Could you point where I said that using should be included in a header?!

Comment: It's in the title of the original question, on the top of the page... `C++ 'string' does not name a type in header`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to miss some semicolons at the end of some lines here:

```
class Game_Map
{
...
    string map_data [50][50]  // Missing ;
public:
    Game_Map(int default_width = 20,int default_height = 20)  // Missing ;
    ~Game_Map() // Missing ;
};
```

Moreover, when you `#include <string>`, the "complete name" to identify the STL string class is `std::string` (since the STL string class is located under the `std::` namespace).

So, just use **`std::string`** instead of `string` in this line:

```
std::string map_data[50][50];
```

Note that in header files you shouldn't use "using directives" (e.g. `using namespace std;`), to avoid to "pollute" the global namespace of clients that #include your header file.
Just specify the STL class names with their `std::` prefix in header files.