# Why am I getting a redefinition error c++?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Error from this file `heap.h`. Error from redefinition of MAX_HEAP, and `heapclass`. 
I keep on getting an error that its redefinition yet, I do not see another definition. Any other reasons?
    The error is found here.

```
// *********************************************************
// Header file Heap.h for the ADT heap.
// *********************************************************

#include "Data.h"  // definition of itemClass

const int MAX_HEAP = 20;
typedef itemClass keyType;

typedef itemClass heapItemType;

class heapClass
{
public:
    heapClass();  // default constructor
    // copy constructor and destructor are
    // supplied by the compiler

    // heap operations:
    virtual bool HeapIsEmpty() const;
    // Determines whether a heap is empty.
    // Precondition: None.
    // Postcondition: Returns true if the heap is empty;
    // otherwise returns false.

    virtual void HeapInsert(const heapItemType& NewItem,
                            bool& Success);
    // Inserts an item into a heap.
    // Precondition: NewItem is the item to be inserted.
    // Postcondition: If the heap was not full, NewItem is
    // in its proper position and Success is true;
    // otherwise Success is false.

    virtual void HeapDelete(heapItemType& RootItem,
                            bool& Success);
    // Retrieves and deletes the item in the root of a heap.
    // This item has the largest search key in the heap.
    // Precondition: None.
    // Postcondition: If the heap was not empty, RootItem
    // is the retrieved item, the item is deleted from the
    // heap, and Success is true. However, if the heap was
    // empty, removal is impossible and Success is false.

protected:
    void RebuildHeap(int Root);
    // Converts the semiheap rooted at index Root
    // into a heap.

private:
    heapItemType Items[MAX_HEAP];  // array of heap items
    int          Size;             // number of heap items
};  // end class
// End of header file.


here are the other files included
main contains main
```

[main](http://pastebin.com/Bnu97WEL)

[Data.cpp](http://pastebin.com/wtqm4dhT)

[Data.h](http://pastebin.com/FdZqZ67t)

[Heap.cpp](http://pastebin.com/PEppbDFz)

[PQ.cpp](http://pastebin.com/BhUMyHg7)

[PQ.h](http://pastebin.com/JYqSeC4a)

```
Thank you
```

Comment: I suspect you are getting this file included more than once since you don't have include guards.

Comment: PQ.h includes "Heap.h" . Heap.cpp inclueds "Heap.h". MAX_HEAP is defined twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"`#pragma once`" should be used to prevent multiple inclusion of the contents of the header files. 
See: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4141z1cx.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Also see: 
[Is #pragma once a safe include guard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787533/is-pragma-once-a-safe-include-guard)

Comment: All "#pragma"s are compiler specific extensions.