# Infinite compilation loop with #include

Tags: c++, loops, compilation, c-preprocessor, header-files

If I have two files like below

```
//file1.h
#include "file2.h"
//file2.h
#include "file1.h"
```

This kind of loop dependency can occur with more than two files, just for the sake of simplicity I listed only two. What happens in this kind of situation?
I am also interested to know if the C++ standard restricts this kind of situation to happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard does not restrict such recursion. Common practice to avoid it is to use

[**include-guards**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)

```
#ifndef FILE_H
#define FILE_H

// content of the header file

#endif
```

or [**`#pragma once`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once):

```
#pragma once

// content of the header file
```

Please note that `#pragma one`, although supported by many compilers, is not a part of the standard:

> `#pragma once` is a non-standard but widely supported preprocessor directive

Comment: It should be mentioned that #pragma once is not standard C++ (or C) whereas header guards are standard. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/787539/5226168.

Comment: @Anders Makes sense. Included.