# Member function definition outside of class

Tags: c++, function, declaration, definition

Is it possible to define function or method outside class declaration?
Such as:

```
class A 
{
    int foo;
    A (): foo (10) {}
}

int A::bar () 
{
    return foo;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to define but not declare a method outside of the class, similar to how you can prototype functions in C then define them later, ie:

```
class A 
{
    int foo;
    A (): foo (10) {}
    int bar();
}

// inline only used if function is defined in header
inline int A::bar () { return foo; }
```

Comment: @Rakete1111 I think, but I dont remember too well that it is implicit if the body is inside the class declaration, but not if done outside like this (honestly reason enough for me just to declare inlines inside the class normally)

Comment: @Rakete1111 No. You'll end up with _multiple definition_ errors, otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but you have to *declare* it first in the class, then you can define it elsewhere (typically the source file):

```
// Header file
class A 
{
    int foo = 10;
    int bar(); // Declaration of bar
};

// Source file
int A::bar() // Definition of bar 
{
    return foo;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can *define* a method outside of your class

```
// A.h
#pragma once
class A 
{
public:
    A (): foo (10) {}
    int bar();
private:
    int foo;
};

// A.cpp
int A::bar () 
{
    return foo;
}
```

But you cannot *declare* a method outside of your class. The declaration must at least be within the class, even if the definition comes later. This is a common way to split up the declarations in `*.h` files and implementations in `*.cpp` files.

Comment: I like this answer a lot, but please dont use pragma once, it encourages people to use non-standard language extensions (assuming it didn't become standard while I wasn't looking in which case disregard this.)

Comment: @Vality No it hasn't, but every major compiler implements it, so it is not *that* big of a problem :)

Comment: @Vality Normally I'd agree with you, I almost always prefer being standard compliant. However in the case of `#pragma once` I don't expect any major compiler to ever not support it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787533/is-pragma-once-a-safe-include-guard

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can declare a method/function inside the class and can define it outside the class with using Class name
with scope resoultion operator before it like.

```
class Calculator{
    int num1,num2;
public:
    void setData(int x, int y){
        num1 = x; num2 = y;
    }
    //Declaration of sum function inside the class
    int sum();
};
// Definition of sum function outside the class
int Calculator::sum(){
    return num1+num2;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible to define a member function out side the class .
There are 2 ways to define member function.

We can define inside the class definition
Define outside the class definition using the scope operator.

To define a member function outside the class definition we have to use the

scope **resolution:: operator** along with the class name and function name.
For more you can read the best example with explanation [**here**](https://rulshi.blogspot.com/2022/08/class-in-c-simple-explanation.html)

Comment: What does this answer add to already existing answers?