# C - typedef across include files

Tags: c

I'm currently working on a c project and to keep my code organized I use include files. One file `includes.h` has a `typedef` and I wan't to access this in a different included file `util.h/util.c`. I included them both in `main.c` in the following order: `includes.h` `util.h`.

`main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//similar includes

#include "includes.h"
#include "util.h"

int main()
{
    MyStructType somename;
    somename.number = 5;

    util_foo(somename);
    return 0;
}
```

`includes.h`:

```
#pragma once
struct structname
{
    int number;
};

typedef struct structname MyStructType;
```

`util.h`:

```
#pragma once

#include "includes.h" //added line (>accepted answer)

int util_foo(MyStructType blabla);
```

`util.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "util.h"

int util_foo(MyStructType blabla)
{
    printf("%d\n", blabla.number);
    return 0;
}
```

I compile with this command: `gcc -o main *.c`

But this doesn't compile, do you have any idea why this doesn't work? Or how to fix it without changing my projects' structure completely?

---

Edit:
It is recommended to replace `#pragma once` with:

```
#ifndef STH_SIMILAR_TO_FILENAME
#define STH_SIMILAR_TO_FILENAME
//code
#endif
```

Comment: Questions about compiler errors should always include the complete error message.

Comment: Will do that next time, I thought it wasn't necessary because it wasn't an explicit error, but me getting the system behind includes wrong.

Comment: Personally, I don't like `#pragma once`.  It's non-standard, and it has one serious and IMO fatal flaw.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787533/is-pragma-once-a-safe-include-guard

Comment: Thanks, going to change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add

```
#include "includes.h"
```

in `util.h` in order to make your code compile.

---

This is because you're relying on *transitive `#include` directives* to get the `MyStructType` typedef into `util.h` from `main.c`, but you're not doing the same in `util.c`.

The best solution *(for maintainability purposes)* is to  minimize relying on transitive inclusions: you should include `includes.h` wherever it's needed *(in this case, in `util.h`)*.