# C++ Beginner: expected unqualified-id before 'int'

Tags: c++, oop, arduino

As you might guess from this question I am quite new to oop programming with c++. (I did only Java before)
Anyways, I am trying to create a custom class for an Arduino project and get the mentioned error. Here are my files:

Header Touchable.h

```
#ifndef Touchable
#define Touchable
#include <Adafruit_TFTLCD.h>

#include <Arduino.h>

class Touchable {
  public:
    int posX;
    int posY;
    Touchable(int, int); //<-- Error here
    ~Touchable();
    void Touchable::draw();
};

#endif
```

And Touchable.cpp

```
#include "Touchable.h" //include the declaration for this class
#include <Adafruit_TFTLCD.h>


Touchable::Touchable(int x, int y) {
  posX = x;
  posY = y;
}

Touchable::~Touchable() {
  /*nothing to destruct*/
}

//turn the LED on
void Touchable::draw() {
  //tft.fillRect(posX, posY, 100, 100, 0x0000);
}
```

EDIT:
Compiler message:

```
In file included from sketch/Touchable.cpp:1:0:
Touchable.h:11: error: expected unqualified-id before 'int'
     Touchable(int x, int y);
               ^
Touchable.h:11: error: expected ')' before 'int'
Touchable.h:12: error: expected class-name before '(' token
     ~Touchable();
               ^
Touchable.h:13: error: invalid use of '::'
     void Touchable::draw();
                          ^
Touchable.h:14: error: abstract declarator '<anonymous class>' used as declaration
 };
 ^
Touchable.cpp:5: error: expected id-expression before '(' token
 Touchable::Touchable(int x, int y) {
                     ^
Touchable.cpp:10: error: expected id-expression before '~' token
 Touchable::~Touchable() {
            ^
exit status 1
expected unqualified-id before 'int'
```

Comment: if you put int x, and int y, in your header does it compile?

Comment: The only problem I see is the extra qualification in Touchable::draw() (remove the Touchable::).

Comment: Nope, same error

Comment: Please provide exact error as given by compiler.

Comment: @PedroBoechat still the same problem

Comment: Alright I wanted to make sure it wasn't some weird issue with whatever compiler you are using.  But I think LogicStuff solved it already.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to pick a different name for your include guard macro (commonly `TOUCHABLE_H`), because preprocessor translates your code in `Touchable.h` to:

```
class {
public:
   int posX;
   int posY;
   (int, int);
   ~();
   void ::draw();
};
```

same goes for all files that `#include` this one... Or you can use [`#pragma once`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787533/is-pragma-once-a-safe-include-guard).

Comment: Good catch. That's why there is rule to use all uppercase in macro and not use them in code.

Comment: Damn, I wouldn't guess for ages :D So simple though

Comment: For example like this: #ifndef _Touchable
#define _Touchable ?

Comment: @user7408924 its generally best to use all caps for macros so `#ifndef TOUCHABLE_H` `#define TOUCHABLE_H`

Comment: @user7408924 [That's reserved for standard implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).