# Using a struct across multiple files

Tags: c++, qt, struct

I am fairly new to the idea of using a struct and I am running into a problem. I have the following struct called Loginput created in mainwindow.h

mainwindow.h

```
    struct Loginput{

    QString logInput1[4];
    QString logInput2[4];
    QString logInput3[4];
    QString logInput4[4];
    QString logInput5[4];
    QString logInput6[4];
    QString logInput7[4];
    QString logInput8[4];
    QString logInput9[4];
    QString logInput10[4];
    QString logInput11[4];
    QString logInput12[4];
    QString logInput13[4];
    QString logInput14[4];
    QString logInput15[4];
    QString logInput16[4];
    QString logInput17[4];
    QString logInput18[4];
    QString logInput19[4];
    QString logInput20[4];

};
```

(yes, i know that's a lot of variables, not interested in that for the moment)

printdialog.h

```
signals:
void printCSV(QString getSerial, QString getCust, Loginput l);
```

Because the struct was created in mainwindow.h the compiler is saying "Loginput has not been declared" when it gets to printdialog.h
How can I create a structure in x header file and then refer to it in y header file?

Comment: One include file can #include another

Comment: printdialog.h already #include "mainwindow.h"

Comment: Define your `struct` in `Loginput.h` file and `#include "Loginput.h"` in `mainwindow.h` and everywhere else you use it. Use `#pragma once` or a header guard.

Comment: thanks for this but how exactly do I use #pragma once?

Comment: @JoeSowerby You type `#pragma once` at the beginning of the file

Answer (score 0):

Move your struct definition to separate file:

`Llginput.h` :

```
#pragma once

#include <QString>

struct Loginput{
    QString logInput1[4];
    QString logInput2[4];
    QString logInput3[4];
    QString logInput4[4];
    QString logInput5[4];
    QString logInput6[4];
    QString logInput7[4];
    QString logInput8[4];
    QString logInput9[4];
    QString logInput10[4];
    QString logInput11[4];
    QString logInput12[4];
    QString logInput13[4];
    QString logInput14[4];
    QString logInput15[4];
    QString logInput16[4];
    QString logInput17[4];
    QString logInput18[4];
    QString logInput19[4];
    QString logInput20[4];

};
```

Then include this file in your `mainwindow.h` file `#include "Loginput.h"`. Also `#include "Loginput.h"` in any other source that needs the definition of `Loginput`, the `#pragma once` directive guarantees that it will not be included more than once per compilation unit.

[Related question about header guards and pragma once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787533/is-pragma-once-a-safe-include-guard)