# including a header file in the .c file that contains its definitions

Tags: c

I have the following files:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test.h"

int main(){
    printf("%d", testFunction());
    return 0;
}
```

test.h

```
int testFunction();
```

test.c

```
int testFunction(){
    return 1;
}
```

should i include test.h in test.c?

test.c

```
#include "test.h" //is this necessary?

int testFunction(){
    return 1;
}
```

If I run the main, there are no errors in either case.

Comment: Not necessary in your specific case, but usually is done because headers might contain some declarations needed for the implementation. Don't forget include guards BTW

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/286490/what-is-the-difference-between-function-and-functionvoid/287002  Summary: use `int testFunction(void)` instead of `int testFunctio()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: should i include test.h in test.c?

A: Generally, yes.

It's *essential* with a more complex header that contains constants, struct definitions, etc.  It's "good practice" in any case.

ALSO:
Don't forget to add [header guards](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/header-guards/) to your .h file.

EXAMPLE:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

int testFunction();

#endif
```

If you prefer, most compilers also support [#pragma once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787533/is-pragma-once-a-safe-include-guard) as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary in your case, but may save you from trouble as your program gets more complicated.
A function declaration
e.g.

```
int f1(int x);
```

should be seen by the compiler before the function call
e.g.

```
return f1(5);
```

so that it knows what to expect.
Using a header file
myheader.h

```
int f1(int x);
```

and main.c

```
#include "myheader.h"

int main(){
    return f1(5);
}

int f1(int x){
    return x*x;
}
```

ensures this is happening, try removing the header file in this example and you get into trouble...